# Не видит view index.php yii2

Tags: php, yii2

[img]http://s011.radikal.ru/i316/1709/9d/95cb9f2c7712.png
[img]http://s019.radikal.ru/i637/1709/9e/d148c75ff3db.png

Проблема такая-сгенерировал модель Product, потом в crud ProductController,ProductSearch и views/Product

все сгенерировало нормально.Перехожу на myhost.ru/product и выходит ошибка(первый скрин).не видит свой views/product/index.php.То же самое и с create и остальными action.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема??

Comment: 2 скрина с пустым subline

Comment: Konstantin Okhotnick не понял,что это значит?? оба скрина с фото

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте во views папку product с маленькой буквы прописать